# Binding Indy TidHttpServer with one of the Network cards

Tags: delphi, http, indy

I have a webservice implemented on delphi xe2 using Indy 10 TidHttpServer working very well in a local area network.

The problem that I found is in a computer with 2 network cards, one a regular NIC that works fine, and the other one a virtual NIC that routes traffic to a x.25 line connected to the phone company for credit card processing.

If the server gets rebooted (and I they like to do that frequently) windows is mounting the virtual NIC first and my server gets bind to it somehow. I do not understand how it works at all.

I read on the documentation from indy that it should be binding to all ips, an should be listening for both networks. However that is not happening. I am basically using the default configuration, except for the port that is assigned to 8888.

Is there a way to exclude this nic from indy http server?

I am looking for an example if possible.

The local network is in the 192.* range, and the virtual nic is in 187.* range. Today to make it work I need to disable the virtual nic, load my server and then enable back again the virtual nic. Works fine. But if get rebooted, I need to do all that again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind your server to a specific card by manually adding and configuring a *binding* before activating the server. A basic example would be something like this:

```
uses IdSocketHandle;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SHandle: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  TIdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear; //make sure there's no other bindings
  SHandle := IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add;
  SHandle.IP := '192.168.0.15';
  SHandle.Port := 3748;
  IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
end;
```

As you can see, the example is done using a `TIdTCPServer`. It works for any `TIdCustomTCPServer`descendant, including `TIdHTTPServer`.

Comment: Minor suggestion: use `IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear` to clear existing bindings first, to avoid open sockets (for example on the default IP address)

Comment: is it possible to have some kind of mask to define the ip? most of the time the IP range is 192.* and 10.* that are the local area ips, for that case I will almost never needs to configure.

Comment: eelias, you have to use an actual IP address to make the binding, but you can iterate over all the IP's at runtime to find the one that matches any criteria you want and then configure the binding.

Comment: Small remark, I was first with the answer but I will delete my answer because they are the same :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy I didn't noticed that, I'm not used to steal points here, so I really sorry about it.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Maybe my error, I am new here, and I saw the messa of jachguate first and he has one thing more that makes it more complete that is the bindings.clear. I am sorry if I did wrong

Comment: I'm not mad, it was just a remark. Anyway jachguate's answer was more "complete" than mine so I really don't mind ;)